# ASP.NET takes time to load AFTER executing the controller's code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but - if I'm not wrong - this is *not* a duplicate. My issue seems slightly different.

As many others I experience a deadly slow loading of my ASP.NET application, but please consider the following:

- no matter IIS or VisualStudio embedded one
- browsers don't make any difference
- the developer pane says nothing about: i.e. the load will be completed in less than 100 ms
- it happens with both localhost or 127.0.0.1 (or even with the actual ip)
- the data to show is very few (less than 10 records)
- **if I put a breakpoint in the controller's code it will be hit immediately when the page is requested. Then the code is executed until the return instruction. AFTER that the browser hangs for dozen of seconds "waiting a connection" to localhost.**

To me, the last thing makes no sense. If the controller's code is executed it means the GET request has *already* sent (and received) and of course also the connection to the host.

Here an actual example of one of my controllers:

```
using PagedList;
using MyProject.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class EventsController : Controller
    {
        private MyContext db = new MyContext();

        // GET: Events
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            int pageSize = 15;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(db.Events.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        // GET: Clear
        public async Task<ActionResult> Clear()
        {
            await db.ClearEvents(true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you actually running DB query in the view. 99% ToPagedList is lazy load and whole controller does not even talk to DB... (If one taken from http://extensionmethod.net/1882/csharp/queryover/topagedlist it is definitely the case).

Comment: If your question is "Why ASP.Net MVC runs view code *after* controller code is done" - because it is build that way (but you need to [edit] post to clarify what exactly you are confused about).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ToPagedList is from here: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList. If it might be the same scenario how should I fix that?

Comment: No, my main question is to understand how to fix the long delay. As side note, I'm wondering why the browser waits for a connection that is already happened.

Comment: A quick try: adding `_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` changes nothing.

Comment: "... until the return instruction. AFTER that the browser hang..." - your return statement is doing all the work.  What happens if you replace `return View(...doLotsOfWork())` by `var model = doLotsOfWork(); return View(model);`?

Comment: Nothing changes. My description wasn't very good. The debugger quickly steps out from the return statement (or from the `doLotsOfWork()`) and immediately jumps to the closing brace. If I'm not wrong that means there isn't a *lot* of work to do, actually...

Comment: @Mark So you understand that controller's action simply prepares DB query but *does not* actually run it, than after controller's action finishes the DB query is executed by view's code to render whatever items you are interested in (taking presumably lot of time)... Now what exactly you don't understand about guess that all hard and slow work is likely done by view in your case?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are issuing a redirect.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events");
```

After your breakpoint has passed, the browser reads the redirect header and requests Index/Events (or whatever it maps to).  At that point there is still nothing to display. The browser has to wait for Index/Events to respond before you will see anything.

Comment: The redirect happens only when requesting "Clear". In all other (and most common) cases the Index is requested and there I return a View.